# Why do we use Do While instead of While in Circular Linked List?

Tags: list, circular-dependency, circular-list

For example i want to add an element at to the beginning list:

```
public void add(int Data){
    //ignoring the possibility that the list is empty
    Node currentNode = head;
    do {
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
    } while (currentNode.getNext() != head);
    Node newNode = new Node(Data);
    newNode.setNext(head);
    currentNode.setNext(newNode);
    head = newNode;
```

What troubles can it cause if we use a while loop in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see your example code is incorrect, at the end of the while the currentNode will be head but you need to stop at the node before the head.

Your stop condition should be:

```
...
}
while (currentNode.getNext() != head)
```

There will be no troubles if you use a while loop. All you need to do is to start from the next node after head and go until the node before head.

```
Node currentNode = head.getNext();
// @todo: test first if the currentNode is null 

while (currentNode.getNext() != head) {
   currentNode = currentNode.getNext()
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction I missed it. Actually, I didn't understand the reason why our lecturer uses Do While loop in Circular while uses While loop in other data structures (i.e single, doubly, multi ...)

Comment: Idk, the only think I can say is that you can use both of them in almost every situations. The Do While loop is used when at least one iteration need to be done because the condition is checked at the end of the iteration.